# formatting double value for pricing data in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a pricing table, I want to convert the data as shown in below. 
Is there a specific way to do it other than doing mod and having a if condition

***Original input = Output I needed***

> 123.0 = 123
>
> 22.2 = 22.2
>
> 22.21 =  22.21

This is for javascript <del>not Java</del>.

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing? seems doable......! ;)

Comment: yeah with mod operation and with a condition but just want to verify if there is an already  defined method or a way

Comment: okay let me ask straight forward, What did you try?

Comment: maybe your `Number#toString()` is overloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `toString()` to get rid of trailling zeroes after decimal like this

```
var n = 123.0;

n = parseFloat(n.toString()) //outputs 123
```

make a method out of it

```
function removeTraillingZeroes( n ){ return parseFloat(n.toString())  }

removeTraillingZeroes( 123.3430 ); //outputs  123.343

removeTraillingZeroes( 123.330 ); //outputs  123.33
```

**Note** - You will need to assign the value back to n, if you want to use the same variable.

```
var n = 123.0;
n = removeTraillingZeroes( n ); //outputs 123
console.log(n);
```

Comment: @Jai since only trailing zeroes are removed after decimal, I don't think it will affect any pricing calculations. unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: n = parseFloat(n.toString()) //outputs 123.0 not 123

Comment: @user1269524 which browser? I tested it on chrome it outputs 123 only.

Comment: Im working on a jaggeryjs project maybe its an issue with that will check, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Just return the values!

```js
var array = [123.0, 22.2, 22.21];

document.write(array.join('<br>'));
```

Comment: `22.2 = 22.2` doesn't match. Interesting requirement from the poster.

Comment: @Jai, the requirements have changed.

Comment: Yup! Agreed, i saw that when posted it was `22.2=22.20` at that time.